# Unit testing a java class extending Stored Procedure with EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock, java-stored-procedures

When I try to unit test the following class extending StoredProcedure I am getting an NullPointerException at the line: `return (Map) execute(csc, new CallableStatementCallback()` in `JDBCTemplate` class. I mocked the bean that is being passed in `execute` method, `DataSource`, and the sql.

```
public class MyStoredProc extends StoredProcedure {
    /**
     * Constructor - sets SQLParameters for the stored procedure.
     * 
     * @param ds - DataSource
     */
    public MyStoredProc(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
        super(dataSource, sql);
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("return",Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("BATCH_ID",Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("PROCESS_TYPE",Types.VARCHAR));

        complie(); 
    }

    public BigDecimal execute(MyBean bean){
        BigDecimal returnValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(-1);

        Map in = new HashMap();

        in.put("BATCH_ID", bean.getBatchID());
        in.put("PROCESS_TYPE", bean.getProcessType());

        Object obj = execute(in);
        if (obj != null) {
            Object output = ((HashMap) obj).get("return"); 

            if( output instanceof BigDecimal) {
                returnValue = (BigDecimal)output;
            }
        }
        return bigDec; 
    }
}
```

test case: P.S - When I debug this test case, StoredProcedure mock is not being used at all.Instead the actual implementation is used.

```
public class MyStoredProcTest {
private MyStoredProc mysp;
private DataSource dataSource;
private String sql;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    dataSource = EasyMock.createMock(DataSource.class);
    sql = "Testing";
    mysp = new MyStoredProc(dataSource, sql);
}

@Test
public void testExecute() {

    StoredProcedure storedProcedure = EasyMock
            .createMock(StoredProcedure.class);
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("return", BigDecimal.ONE);
    expect(storedProcedure.execute(EasyMock.anyObject(Map.class))).andReturn(map);

    Connection con = EasyMock.createMock(Connection.class);
    expect(dataSource.getConnection()).andReturn(con);   
    MyBean bean = EasyMock.createMock(MyBean.class);


    expect(bean.getBatchID()).andReturn(BigDecimal.valueOf(.0001))
            .anyTimes();
    expect(bean.getProcessType()).andReturn("Process Type").anyTimes();

    replay(bean, dataSource, storedProcedure, con);
    BigDecimal returnValue = null;
    try {
        returnValue = mysp.execute(bean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception" + e.getStackTrace());//  the Null pointer from JDBCTemplate is caught here.
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(-1), returnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your mocks are not being used because you are not replaying them.  You should modify `replay(bean)` to `replay(bean, datasource, storedProcedure)`

On another note, `map` does not need to be mocked.  When you expect the call to `storedProcedure.execute(...)` you can return the pre-populated `map`.

Comment: Thanks jradakov...I am still getting the same error.I added replay, created an instance of map instead of mocking it per your suggestion and added a mock for connection (as it gave me an unexpected call to getConnection)

Comment: I forgot to add "con" to replay...did that and getting a different error now...will try to resolve it and post if any help is needed